# Accessing Dell RAC(DRAC) card from the Internet

Tags: remote-access, dell-poweredge

How do I access my Dell Server DRAC card from the Internet so I can turn it on, reboot, etc. my server from anywhere?

Answer (score 8):

Ok after some digging(guess I shoulda looked harder first, lol. sorry) I found out I need to forward some ports on my router and it works!!. Thanks any-ways.

Here's how to do it:
[http://onlinetechadvice.blogspot.com](http://onlinetechadvice.blogspot.com/2010/10/accessing-dell-racremote-access.html)

```
       Forward the following ports on your router:
       Port: 80
       Port: 5900
       Port: 443
```